# Write query result to txt file

Tags: php, sql, oracle

The query results come from the oracle how to write to a text file in php.These codes write to html table.I want implement as write text fle.

```
<?php

    $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT POSTAL_CODE, CITY FROM locations WHERE ROWNUM < 3');
    oci_execute($stid);

    $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);

    foreach ($res as $col) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($col as $item) {
            echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "")."</td>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the entire result and write it in JSON:

```
function save_result($result, $location) {
 $json = json_encode($result); // Convert $result into a json formatted string
 $file = fopen($location, 'w'); // Open the file to write
 fwrite($file, $json); // Write to file
 fclose($file); // Close up
}
```

---

```
function get_result($result, $location) {
 $file = fopen($location, 'r'); // Open the file to read
 $read = json_decode(fread($file, filesize($location))); // Decode json formated string into an asoc array
 fclose($location); // Close up
 return $read;
}
```

---

Usage:

```
save_result($result, 'hello.txt'); // Save

get_result('hello.txt'); // Read
```